# The Space $S^1\vee S^1$ as a deformation retract of the punctured torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, retraction

> Let $T^2=S^1\times S^1$ be the torus and $p\in T^2$. Show that the punctured torus $T^2-\{p\}$ has the figure eight $S^1\vee S^1$ as a deformation retract.

The torus $T^2$ is homeomorphic to the quotient space: $$I\times I/\sim$$ where $I=[-1,1]$ and $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by $(1,t)\sim (-1,t)$ and $(s,-1)\sim (s,1)$. Also, $S^1\vee S^1$ is homeomorphic to $\partial (I\times I)/\sim$.

Now, it is easy to show that the family of maps $\{f_\lambda\}$ given by:
$$f_\lambda(s,t)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
\lambda(\frac{s}{|s},\frac{t}{|t|})+(1-\lambda)(s,t), &\text{if}& |s|\geq |t|\\
\lambda(\frac{s}{|t|},\frac{t}{|t|})+(1-\lambda)(s,t), &\text{if}& |t|\geq |s|
\end{array}\right.$$
defines a deformation retraction of $I\times I-\{(0,0)\}$ onto $\partial (I\times I)$.

My question is:

- *How can I prove that the family $\{f_\lambda\}$ induces a retraction given by:*
  $$\begin{array}{rcll}
  \hat f_\lambda:&T^2-\{p\}\cong (I\times I-\{(0,0)\})/\sim &\longrightarrow & S^1\vee S^1\cong \partial(I\times I)/\sim\\
  &[(s,t)]&\longmapsto &[f_\lambda(s,t)]
  \end{array}$$
  *?*
- *Is there some property that ensures that it is a retraction between the quotient spaces?*

Comment: I don't think your deformation retraction is quite accurate.

Comment: I've made a mistake! I have corrected it in the post

Comment: Your formula still confuses me. I don't think you want $\frac{s}{|t|}$ anywhere in there.